# Loading embedding model form Hugging Face in Llama Index throws up an attribute error

Tags: google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers, llama-index, llama-cpp-python

I am trying to load embeddings like this.I changed the code to reflect the current version change in LlamaIndex but it shows up an attribute error.

```
from llama_index.embeddings.huggingface import HuggingFaceEmbedding
from llama_index.core import Settings
Settings.embed_model = HuggingFaceEmbedding(
    model_name="BAAI/bge-small-en-v1.5"
)
```

AttributeError: module 'torch._subclasses' has no attribute 'functional_tensor'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py in _get_module(self, module_name)
1364             return importlib.import_module("." + module_name, self.**name**)
1365         except Exception as e:
-> 1366             raise RuntimeError(
1367                 f"Failed to import {self.**name**}.{module_name} because of the following error (look up to see its"
1368                 f" traceback):\n{e}"

RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.models.bert.modeling_bert because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
module 'torch._subclasses' has no attribute 'functional_tensor'

This is happening when I am trying to load the reranker as well.

```
from llama_index.core.postprocessor import SentenceTransformerRerank
rerank = SentenceTransformerRerank(
    model="cross-encoder/ms-marco-MiniLM-L-12-v2", top_n=3 
)
```

I tried to upgrade the libraries and reinstalling llama index but its not working.

!pip uninstall llama-index
!pip install llama-index --upgrade --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall

!pip install --upgrade torch
!pip install --upgrade transformers

I am running this on Google Colab.
Thank you if you help in this.

Answer (score 0):

Check for your torch version
!python -c "import torch; print(torch.**version**)"

Downgrading it works

!python -m pip install --upgrade torch==1.13.0

Answer (score 0):

you will have to install `llama-index-embeddings-huggingface` as well .

Try next command:

```
pip install llama-index-embeddings-huggingface
```